# How to apply Toggle method for another method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script with jquery, and it is running but not as expected, I do not know where the location is wrong.

```
<img onclick="$(this).click('toggle', function(){
    $(this).animate({width : '1024px', height : '500px'});
},function(){ 
    $(this).animate({width : '100px', height : '100px'}); 
});" class="magnify" src="a.jpg" border="1" alt="cantik_1" width="200" height="auto" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
<script language="javascript"> 

$(document).ready(function(){    


 $("#img1").toggle(function(){
     $(this).animate({width : '1024px', height : '500px'});
 },function(){ 
     $(this).animate({width : '100px', height : '100px'}); 
 });

 });
</script>





<img id="img1" class="magnify" src="a.jpg" border="1" alt="cantik_1" width="200" height="auto" />
```

Comment: Thanks friend, but this does not change the condition, the result is still the same as before.

Comment: I've applied into the script, then double the action occurs. option 1 and option 2.

Comment: I've applied into the script, then double the action occurs. option 1 and option 2.

Comment: try with the 
$(document).ready(function() updated above .. the issue was before.. and now its fixed.. working fine in my end

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3951/discussion-between-mithunsatheesh-and-ukung)